# Ignore or display NA in a row if the search word is not available in a list- R

Tags: r

How to print or display Not Available if any of my search list in (Table_search) is not available in the list I input. In the input I have three lines and I have 3 keywords to search through these lines and tell me if the keyword is present in those lines or not. If present print that line else print Not available like I showed in the desired output.

My code just prints all the available lines but that doesn't help as I need to know where is the word is missing as well.

```
Table_search        <- list("Table 14", "Source Data:","VERSION")
Table_match_list    <- sapply(Table_search, grep, x = tablelist, value = TRUE)
```

Input:

```
Table 14.1.1.1 (Page 1 of 2)
Source Data: Listing 16.2.1.1.1
Summary of Subject Status by Respiratory/Non-Ambulatory at Event Entry
```

Desired Output:

```
Table 14.1.1.1 (Page 1 of 2)
Source Data: Listing 16.2.1.1.1
NA
```

@r2evans

sapply(unlist(Table_search), grepl, x = dat)

I get a good output with this code actually, but instead of true or false I would like to print the actual data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a single regex will do it:

```r
replace(dat, !grepl(paste(unlist(Table_search), collapse="|"), dat), NA)
# [1] "Table 14.1.1.1 (Page 1 of 2)"    "Source Data: Listing 16.2.1.1.1"
# [3] NA
```

One problem with using `sapply(., grep)` is that `grep` returns integer indices, and if no match is made then it returns a length-0 vector. For `sapply` (a class-unsafe function), this means that you may or may not get a `integer` vector in return. Each return may be length 0 (nothing found) or length 1 (something found), and when `sapply` finds that each return value is not exactly the same length, it returns a `list` instead (ergo my "class-unsafe" verbiage above).

This doesn't change when you use `value=TRUE`: change my reasoning above about *"0 or 1 `logical`"* into *"0 or 1 `character`"*, and it's the same exact problem.

Because of this, I suggest `grepl`: it should always return `logical` indicating found or not found.

Further, since you don't appear to need to differentiate *which* of the patterns is found, just "at least one of them", then we can use a single regex, joined with the regex-OR operator `|`. This works with an arbitrary length of your `Table_search` list.

If you somehow needed to know *which* of the patterns was found, then you might want something like:

```r
sapply(unlist(Table_search), grepl, x = dat)
#      Table 14 Source Data: VERSION
# [1,]     TRUE        FALSE   FALSE
# [2,]    FALSE         TRUE   FALSE
# [3,]    FALSE        FALSE   FALSE
```

and then figure out what to do with the different columns (each row indicates a string within the `dat` vector).

One way (that is doing the same as my first code suggestion, albeit less efficiently) is

```r
rowSums(sapply(unlist(Table_search), grepl, x = dat)) > 0
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

where the logical return value indicates if something was found. If, for instance, you want to know if two or more of the patterns were found, one might use `rowSums(.) >= 2)`.

---

Data

```r
Table_search <- list("Table 14", "Source Data:","VERSION")
dat <- c("Table 14.1.1.1 (Page 1 of 2)", "Source Data: Listing 16.2.1.1.1", "Summary of Subject Status by Respiratory/Non-Ambulatory at Event Entry")
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I'll add a similar comment I've posted before, that if you have a large `Table_search` vector you can adapt this to  `replace(tablelist, !Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(Table_search, grepl, x=tablelist)), NA)` to stop the regex growing big and falling over.

Comment: Hi, I have put this through a separate question. Please advise.